# What does getSupportFragmentManager() method returns in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

What does getSupportFragmentManger() method returns ? Also how getSupportFragmentManger() differ from
 getFragmentManger()

Comment: both return a FragmentManager.

Comment: FragmentManager class object right? what is its use?

Comment: can't you just read the documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation for [`getSupportFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()), it returns an [`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html).

[`getFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getFragmentManager()) return an [`android.app.FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html).

The difference is that the support version works with applications supporting Android versions prior to 3.0, while the latter is only available on Android 3.0+.

For more information, see the documentation on the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

It returns an **android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager**.

If you use fragments in your application and want to support android versions prior to 3.0; you have to add Support Library to your application and use android.support.v4.app.Fragment with support fragment manager.